# Java Pdf Renderer support text selection and clipboard copy

Tags: java, pdf, select, copy, icepdf

Does any one know a pdf renderer for Java which supports text selection and clipboard copy the hidden text layer of pdf?

In fact, I'm programing an OCR application which brings docs from the scanner and converts them to a searchable pdf and I'd like to show the result pdf in my application.

I have already tested:

- IcePDF : which supports selecting hidden text but it doesn't support copying
- PDFRender,JPedal which doesn't support selecting hidden text at all
- JmuPDF : which supports everything I want, but it requires a dll to be installed

Comment: icePDF supports copying selected text also.
Finally, what did you use to solve the same?

Comment: i've kept IcePDF and I created an event on `Ctrl + v` that put the selected text on the clipboard I also created a button which do the same.